# How to error the ng build command when circular dependencies detected

Tags: angular-cli, circular-dependency

I'm using Angular 9 and I would like my builds to to fail whenever the circular dependency is detected in the build target.

When I was using Angular 6 and below, I was just adding a Circular Dependency Webkack plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin) to my webpack config and it worked fine. However, in Angular 9, I do not have the access to the wepack config of the builder that is used to build my target. I don't want to use a custom:webpack builder.

Do you know how it can be achieved? I'm aware of the `showCircularDependencies` key in `angular.json` file but it is just there to turn the warnings on and off.

Answer (score 3):

The Angular built-in Circular Dependency webpack plugin is deprecated in Angular 12 and will be removed in the future. The recommended method to detect circular dependencies is to use either a lint rule or other external tooling. ESlint has https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-cycle.md

EDIT:

The ESlint rule is slow, perhaps not surprisingly since ESlint is designed for linting a file at a time and circular dependency checking is all about global information.

We use https://github.com/pahen/madge which is fast and works well.